# Java Prime Factorization with additional algebra

Tags: java

Here is what I am looking to do. I have included my code below my goal for your reference.

Goal: Find Prime Factorizations of a number n. Then concatenate the prime factors into one number, x. Then Take that number, x, and divide by n. If x%n = 0, print True. If x%n != 0, print false. (i.e. if n = 100, Prime Factors are 2,2,5,5. Turn into an integer 2255, then take 2255/100. 2255%100 != 0, Print False. )

What I have now prints out “2 2 5 5” and prints out all prime factors correctly for any n that I put in.

If possible, ideally I would like to run this for numbers k= 2 through any upper bound I set, call the upper bound U, and if any value for k =  2 through U yields a result that is true (from above) Then I would like to print that k value.

```
 import acm.program.*;
import acm.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

public class Factors extends ConsoleProgram
{
    //~ Instance/static variables .............................................
    private RandomGenerator rgen = RandomGenerator.getInstance();
    //~ Constructor ...........................................................
    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Creates a new ForLoops object.
     */
    public void run()
    {

        int n = 100;



        println("The prime factorization of " + n + " is: ");

        // for each potential factor i

        for (int i = 2; i*i <= n; i++) {

            // if i is a factor of N, repeatedly divide it out
            while (n % i == 0) {

                n = n / i;
                print(i+" "); 




                //print(i/n);


            }



        }


        // if biggest factor occurs only once, n > 1
        if (n > 1) println(n);
        else       println();
    }
}
```

Comment: So whats your problem ? You haven't stated a real problem that you have run into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an over-arching for-loop that your existing code goes in like so:

```
int U = 10; //or whatever your limit is

for (int j = 2; j < U; j++) {    

}
```

And you incorporate your algorithm for finding the prime factors by having a StringBuilder that you add your factors to:

```
StringBuilder factors = new StringBuilder();
```

Which you could use like this to add your factors:

```
for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++) {

    // if i is a factor of N, repeatedly divide it out
    while (n % i == 0) {
        n = n / i;
        factors.append(Integer.toString(i));
        print(i + " ");
    }
}
```

Then you could parse your factors.toString like so:

```
int newNumber = Integer.parseInt(factors.toString);
```

Which would give you your number (like 2255 for example). This could then just be put in an if-statment that says "if this number is evenly divisible by n, then print n":

```
if ( newNumber % n == 0 ){
    System.out.println(n);    
}
```

This should at least help you get on your way.

Comment: Ok, so I got that part all worked out. Thanks for the help! I am now having an issue with actually finding the prime factors. When I let n = 100, it gives me 2,2,5,5 which is correct. If I let n = 123 though, the prime factors are 3,41 but it is only giving me 3. Any suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah I ran your code on my machine when I was creating this post, and while I don't know the exact source of the problem, I found that the factorization was only correct for numbers that had multiple identical factors like 4 (2,2) or 9 (3,3). Also, if I helped, accepting my solution is a good way for other users to get more use out of this post. Thanks!

Comment: You can try and brute force it first to get it working, and then edit it to make it more elegant as you go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scanner to take in input, parse it as integer. After that, you can simply print(n) within the while loop.